# How to localize the Visual Studio bootstrapper?

Tags: installation, bootstrapper

I have a wix setup project with the following msbuild bootstraper settings:

```
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" 
  Culture="cs" 
  ApplicationName="Slais" 
  BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" 
  ComponentsLocation="Relative" 
  CopyComponents="True" 
  OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" 
  Path="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\" />
```

When the bootstraper dialog runs it has UI in english. The EULA is changed but the labels and the buttons like "Accept" are still in English. Is it possible to localize the dialog or to skip it? Or to create silent bootstraper other way?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From Wix [How to make your installer localizable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/make_installer_localizable.htm)

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/make_installer_localizable.htm

Comment: I need to localize the bootstrapper dialog, not the installer.

Comment: Sorry maybe this link on installing .net silently without users interaction would http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/16/9553804.aspx